# How to print name in arabic with collection latin1_bin

Tags: html, mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database table and I want to print the name. It isn't displayed correct, it's like this:

```
Abu Noooooora           dddd@hotmail.com
���� �������    dddd@hotmail.com
almojaded               dddd@islamway.net
WeldLibya               dddd@hotmail.com
```

What can I do to print like:

```
Abu Noooooora           dddd@hotmail.com
يوسف على                dddd@hotmail.com
almojaded               dddd@islamway.net
WeldLibya               dddd@hotmail.com
```

My php code is:

```
<?
$dd = mysql_query("SELECT sname,semail FROM senders LIMIT 5");
while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($dd))
{   
?>    
    <tr>        
        <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $ro["sname"]; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $ro["semail"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using MySQL. Suggest you read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset.html.

Can you tell if MySQL is set up for unicode (international) character sets. You can use some of the MySQL admin tools to check this. YOu need to know the name of the character set you want to use, and check if it is loaded into your MySQL installation.

At the HTML level, you need to specify that you are using utf8 output by placing something like 
    
in your header area

Comment: I do that, i set in html file utf8 and in mysql is at Unicode-utf8

Comment: Can you access MySQL directly, either on a server, or using something like phpmysqladmin? I would check there first to see if the characters appear correctly. Do you know what web server your are using (like Apache) and the version number?

Comment: i using phpmysqladmin and with appach last version

Comment: Maybe your text is not encoded as utf8, but in some other char set. You could use an editor such as Textpad to check this.

Comment: Just looked at the title for this question, looks like you sre using latin_1_bin. So you need to convert all text to utf8. Or spcify that charset for MySQL and HTML.